# Exception thrown when executing "save". Laravel Issue

Tags: php, laravel, database, caching

When tried to run the project immediately get an error:

Exception thrown when executing "save". (View: ../Themes/Storefront/views/public/home/index.blade.php)

/vendor/cache/adapter-common/AbstractCachePool.php

```
private function handleException(\Exception $e, $function)
{
    $level = 'alert';
    if ($e instanceof InvalidArgumentException) {
        $level = 'warning';
    }

    $this->log($level, $e->getMessage(), ['exception' => $e]);
    **if (!$e instanceof CacheException) {
        $e = new CachePoolException(sprintf('Exception thrown when executing "%s". ', $function), 0, $e);
    }**

    throw $e;
}
```

I tried to change the cache adapter,driver cache, also I cleaned all cache and changed directory permissions. But persist.

Anyone have another idea or something to help me! Please!

Comment: Have you tried php artisan config:clear?

Comment: Yeah! I tried. But, doesn’t work